# jQuery FancyBox plugin Quick Inquiry

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a quick question on the FancyBox plugin. I don't need help on code, I just need help understanding one thing.

I have been designing the website in NetBeans and every now and then I will use Chrome and refresh the page to see my progress. The site isn't online, and I am just checking via my laptop and Chrome.

I have videos that I want to open in an iframe class, but they don't seem to work. The demo file that came with the downloaded pack states "Will not run from your local computer, requires a server to run." Is this the reason why the youtube videos don't show? Do I need to actually get hosted to see if they work? Can I bypass this by getting the video files themselves and putting them in my root folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with terminal/prompt you can cd into that folder and run this to get a simple server running which might help

In terminal:

python -m SimpleHTTPServer

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Turns out the embed link when you press "share" in youtube doesn't have "http:" at the beginning of the URL so all I had to do was add this.